# Почему не получается заменить элементы строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мой код получает путь к файлу в виде строки. Сейчас путь оформлен двумя слешами \\ - `string = 'C:\\folder\\file'`.

Мне необходимо заменить \\ на / - `C:/folder/file`. Я пытался воспользоваться методом `replace()`, но почему-то это не привело к нужному результату:

```
string = 'C:\\folder\\file'
string.replace('\\', '/')
print(string)
>>> C:\folder\file
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Надо присвоить результат обратно в строку: string = string.replace('\\', '/') сейчас у вас замена происходит, но никуда не присваивается.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я думал, что этот метод изменяет данную строку, а не создает новую

Comment: К сожалению, с этим в Питоне проблема - не всегда интуитивно понятно, что работает inplace, а что выдаёт результат наружу. Бывает и так и так. Хотя не только в Питоне, наверное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STR (СТРОКА)` 
Строка — базовый тип представляющий из себя **`НЕизменяемую`** последовательность символов, 
т.е. если вам надо изменить строку, вы должны создать новую строку.

Запись `string = string.replace('\\', '/')` означает, что вы создаете новый объект.

```
string = 'C:\\folder\\file'
id(string)  # --> 50524656

string = string.replace('\\', '/')
id(string)  # --> 50524592
```